# Linked List and Input

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, nodes

The general goal I have is to be able to enter in a string and have it be added to a list. My main issue has to due with makenewnode. I am fairly confident that main and my struct are solid, i'm somewhat confident in the basic code in search, but the specifics don't look good. My question is essentially, what is wrong with the print statements in main, is using makenewnode twice in search redundant and is makenewnode actually working how it should.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
```

wc (word count) is supposed to hold the list of words in wrd, the number of words in count and next is meant to advance through the list.

```
struct wc {
    struct wc* next;
    char* wrd;
    int count;
};
```

head is meant to be the very beginning of the list

```
struct wc* head=NULL;
```

makenewnode is fairly self-explanatory. It takes char* s, allocates memory, adds to count (supposed to be the number of words in the list) and adds the word to wrd (supposed to be the list of words)

```
void makenewnode(char* s){
    struct wc* newnode;
    char* newword;

    newword=malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    strcpy(newword,s);
    newnode=malloc(sizeof(struct wc));
    newnode->wrd=newword;
    newnode->count=1;
    newnode->next=head;
    head=newnode;
}
```

Search is supposed to take the input string and decide if it is already in the list. The while loop is supposed to run until the end of the input string. It compares wrd (the words already added to the list) with the input and if the input is already in wrd it adds to the count and sets found=1 (just as a symbol, the 1 doesn't actually mean anything). If the input isn't in wrd, it creates a new node for the input using makenewnode. I feel like my else statement and the second if statement are redundant but I am not sure.

```
void search(char* linebuf){
    struct wc* node;
    int found=0;

    found=0;
    node=head;
    while(node!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(node->wrd, linebuf)==0){
            node->count++;
            found=1;
            break;
        }
        else{
            makenewnode(linebuf);

        }

    if(found==0){
        makenewnode(linebuf);
    }
    }
}
```

main is supposed to get the input strings (max of 100 characters) and just run them through search (which runs through makenewnode). Then it should print the number of words (count) and the list of words (wrd)k.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    struct wc* node;
    char linebuf[100];

    printf("Enter Words: ");
    while(fgets(linebuf,100,stdin)!=0){
        printf("Input line: %s", linebuf);
        printf("Enter Words: ");
        search(linebuf);
    }
    /*
    I'm pretty iffy on these print statements but the rest of main is fine (I think)
    printf("%d", count);
    printf("%s", wrd);
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: Would be good post if it had an actual **question**

Comment: For the iffy part, use `%s` instead of `%c` as the latter expects a single character

Comment: Sorry, I was focusing too much on trying to explain it. What I want to know is basically a few mini questions. What is wrong with the print statements in main, is using makenewnode twice in search redundant and is makenewnode actually working how it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search should be:

```
void search(char* linebuf){
    struct wc* node;
    int found;

    node=head;
    found=0;
    while(node!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(node->wrd, linebuf)==0){
            node->count++;
            found=1;
            break;
        }else{
        node = node->next;
        }
    }
    if(found==0){
        makenewnode(linebuf);
    }
}
```

Main should be:

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    struct wc* node;
    char linebuf[100];
    char* inp;

    printf("Enter Words: ");

    while((inp=fgets(linebuf,100,stdin))!=0){
        printf("Input line: %s", inp);
        search(inp);
    }
    node=head;
    while(node!=NULL){
        printf("\nWords: %s\nCount: %d\n", node->wrd,node->count);
        node=node->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The other sections of code are fine.

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
void search(char* linebuf){
    struct wc* node;
    int found=0;

    //found=0;
    node=head;
    while(node!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(node->wrd, linebuf)==0){
            node->count++;
            found=1;
            break;//or return ;
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
    if(found==0){
        makenewnode(linebuf);
    }
}
```